# How lazy loading in quasar q-table pagination limit of data

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm not understand, How lazy loading in quasar q-table pagination limit of data?

Example : 1-10 of 5000 =>pagination

Expectation : Limit 1-10 of 1000
when last page pagination call data again ..
1001-1010 of 2000